# Why are my webpage colors different in other browsers?

Tags: css, colors

I am working on a basic webpage that uses flexbox for formatting. Everything looks fine on the Internet Explorer browser,but when I open the page on chrome, every color turns pink-ish. Do some browsers not support certain colors? If so, can I import them into my css file directly (just like importing fonts)?

Comment: I fixed it temporarily by setting a backup background color. I guess chrome doesn't support the color #F0FF.

Comment: Try with -webkit- params.

Comment: Hex colors should be 3 or 6 characters long.